Maximal Interval Proof for ODEs

Three books have the same idea for a proof where they assume that the interval I is closed at one end.
They can assume that interval can be closed at one because of the existence of the maximal interval, which is what the proof is trying to prove!
I still don't understand why it can be assumed the I is closed at one end, in the proof for the existence of a maximal interval.
It seems like circular logic

I might be missing something here, but something does not seem right. The ODE $x'=x^2$ with $x(0) = 1$ has a maximal interval of existence of the from $(-\infty, 1)$, and it cannot be extended to the right to a closed interval. What text is this from?

Hale JK's  book on ODEs

Hartman does the same type of setup in his book

There is something missing at the start of the proof. Perhaps because the correct construction seems too advanced.

The set of local solutions (that are extensions of $\phi$, $\phi$ being the trivial extension) is not empty, per existence theorem (or the given $\phi$).
The partial-function relation induces a  partial order on the set of local solutions that is also inductive, every chain has a maximal element (possibly not in the chain).
By the Zorn-Kuratovsky lemma the inductive partial ordered set of local solutions has limit points in the order sense. Possibly several as no uniqueness is implied in the statement of the theorem. Each such limit is a maximal solution. This step requires the axiom of choice (a more popular form of the Zorn lemma), similar to the basis selection theorem in infinite-dimensional vector spaces.

Now one can start with the details. Such as

that the domain of a maximal solution can not be closed or semi-closed (with finite values, at infinity it is both). Because at a closed interval end there would be a value of the solution that could serve as initial point for another local solution that would extend the maximal solution.

that the maximal solution can not be confined to any compact subset of the open domain $D$, in both directions. Otherwise there would be a limit and the local solution from it can be patched-on to the not-so-maximal solution.


One can consider the compact subset $K_N$ of $D$ of points with distance not greater than $N$ from the initial point and distance not smaller than $1/N$ from the boundary of $D$. The stated convergence to the boundary follows.

Then do you know where I can find the full proof. I have trouble finding the definition of a limit in a semiorder

I added links to the relevant order theory and, unfortunately only in German, its application to the existence proof of an unextendable solution.

Thanks! That proof was pretty straight forward and Zorn's lemma is not complicated. This makes me scratch my head more as to why it wasn't included in the book given how simple the proof you linked was.
